# finding neighbor cells and their neighbor cells and so on with same value

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, matrix

I have a table like that

```
6 5 6 6 3 6
2 4 6 8 1 5
3 6 6 6 4 6
7 4 2 6 1 8
```

and user chosed 0,2 (6)
I have to find all neighbors of that cell with same value, and their neighbors with same value and so on.
For this table, I need a list like this

```
['0,2','0,3','1,2','2,1','2,2','2,3','3,3']
```

Note : There is no limitation about size of table.

Comment: What is not working with your attempt?

Comment: Hi @EnesEren, have you attempted a solution? If so, please share it with us. (even if it's not working). See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a year I remembered my question and came back to answer my own question since I'm a bit better right now. Here is my solution.

```
def findNeighbors(gameMap,selectedRow,selectedColumn):
    finalNeighbors = [] #the list that we will store final state of neighbor list
    newNeighbors = [] #the list that we will store the new neighbors in every loop
    newNeighborsClone = [] #the list that we will traverse inside after clearing the new neighbor list
    newNeighbors.append([selectedRow,selectedColumn]) #we already have a known neighbor which is chosed one
    selectedNumber = gameMap[selectedRow][selectedColumn] 
    print("Selected number = " + str(selectedNumber))
    while newNeighbors: #while newNeighbors list has an element inside
        finalNeighbors = finalNeighbors + newNeighbors #add every new neighbor to main neighbor list
        newNeighborsClone = newNeighbors[::] #clone the new neighbors list
        newNeighbors = [] #clearing the new neighbors list
        for row,column in newNeighborsClone:
            if row == 0: #if we're at peak we only need to look for down
                if gameMap[row+1][column] == selectedNumber and [row+1,column] not in finalNeighbors: #and to prevent infinite loops, we have to check if its already in final neighbors list
                    newNeighbors.append([row+1,column])
            elif row == (len(gameMap)-1): #if we're at the bottom we only need to look for up
                if gameMap[row-1][column] == selectedNumber and [row-1,column] not in finalNeighbors:
                    newNeighbors.append([row-1,column])
            else: #if we're somewhere at middle we have to look up and down
                if gameMap[row+1][column] == selectedNumber and [row+1,column] not in finalNeighbors:
                    newNeighbors.append([row+1,column])
                if gameMap[row-1][column] == selectedNumber and [row-1,column] not in finalNeighbors:
                    newNeighbors.append([row-1,column])
            if column == 0: #if we're at the left side we only need to look for right
                if gameMap[row][column+1] == selectedNumber and [row,column+1] not in finalNeighbors: 
                    newNeighbors.append([row,column+1])
            elif column == (len(gameMap[0])-1): #if we're at the right side we only need to look for left
                if gameMap[row][column-1] == selectedNumber and [row,column-1] not in finalNeighbors:
                    newNeighbors.append([row,column-1])
            else: #if we're somewhere at middle
                if gameMap[row][column+1] == selectedNumber and [row,column+1] not in finalNeighbors:
                    newNeighbors.append([row,column+1])
                if gameMap[row][column-1] == selectedNumber and [row,column-1] not in finalNeighbors:
                    newNeighbors.append([row,column-1])
    finalNeighbors = deleteDuplicates(finalNeighbors) #Even after all of if elses, there can be still duplicated elements. Better removing them
    return finalNeighbors
```

I couldn't copy my whole code to here I don't know why. But here is the function which assigned to do this job. I could just use a try except block instead of all these if elses, but using try except was banned on that assignment. So I had to do this. You can just check all four sides in a try block instead of that much ifs

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create all the combinations with an offset of 1 from the current coordinates in the matrix and just ditch the ones that have any negative coordinates?